# \clipbox of a \scalebox not working properly in xelatex

Tags: xetex, bugs

Using xelatex... when I apply a `\clipbox` upon a `\scalebox` of a box that uses the optional argument, the clip is not performed properly.

The problem goes away if:

1. using pdflatex,
2. the optional argument to the `\scalebox` is omitted, or
3. the `\clipbox` is omitted.

Here is an unanswered 2014 question that perhaps describes the same problem: [clipbox with bidi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173818/clipbox-with-bidi).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\begin{document}
Works OK without scalebox opt.{} argument

\setbox0=\hbox{XXX}
  \scalebox{1}{\copy0}%
. Now clip it:
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 10pt 0pt}{%
  \scalebox{1}{\copy0}%
}.   

Breaks with scalebox opt.{} argument

\setbox0=\hbox{XXX}
  \scalebox{1}[.5]{\copy0}%
. Now clip it:
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 10pt 0pt}{%
  \scalebox{1}[.5]{\copy0}%
}.   
\end{document}
```

While I use the temporary `\box0` for simplicity, the problem arises also if I use a permanent `\savebox`.  Package loading order has no effect.

Below, the top image is pdflatex, the bottom with xelatex.  Note the bottom-right of the bottom image, which shows an empty result for the clip.

[image]

NOTE: This question arose when Hiemanshu Sharma asked why my method at [Draw Text in different shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313880/draw-text-in-different-shapes/313904#313904) did not work with xelatex.  I boiled it down to the above MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in `trimclip` is an earlier version of the material that is now in the `expl3` drivers. In particular, there are some refinements that are in the XeTeX drivers that are not in `trimclip`. To see this, try the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

A%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { XXX }
\box_scale:Nnn \l_tmpa_box { 1 } { 0.5 }
\box_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box { 0pt } { 0pt } { 10pt } { 0pt }
\box_clip:N \l_tmpa_box
\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
\ExplSyntaxOff
B

\end{document}
```

with pdfTeX and XeTeX.

The code in `trimclip` can be fixed by taking the newer definition and applying it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\@cliptoboxdim#1{%
    \setbox #1=\hbox{%
      \Gin@defaultbp\WIDTH{\wd #1}%
      \Gin@defaultbp \DEPTH {\dp #1}%
      \@tempdima \ht #1%
      \advance\@tempdima\dp#1%
      \Gin@defaultbp \TOTALHEIGHT {\@tempdima }%
      \special{pdf:literal q}% 
      \special{pdf:literal 0 -\DEPTH \space \WIDTH \space \TOTALHEIGHT \space re W n }%
      \rlap{\copy #1}%
      \special {pdf:literal Q}%
      \hskip\wd#1%
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\setbox0=\hbox{XXX}

A%
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 10pt 0pt}{%
  \scalebox{1}[0.5]{\copy0}%
}%
B
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!  It works in your example and, with the patch, in the cited question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313880/draw-text-in-different-shapes/313904#313904