# Create text shapes with custom fonts

Tags: xetex, text

I'm trying to draw text in different shapes using a custom font.

With the help of [Steven](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes), I was able to get most of the text shapes I needed working well. See the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313880/draw-text-in-different-shapes)

Everything works well, except when using custom fonts. I'm using the `fontspec` package with `XeLaTeX` for custom fonts. Below is what I'm using to generate the final output:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen,trimclip,calc,fp,graphicx}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0.2pt}%

\title{bidPress}
\author{bidPress}
\date{September 2016}

\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=/path/to/fonts/]{"HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf"}

\newsavebox\mytext
\newcounter{mycount}
\newlength\clipsize

\newcommand\parabtext[5][0]{%
  \edef\neck{#3}% percent to depress the amplitude
  \def\cuts{#4}% Number of cuts
  \savebox{\mytext}{\kern.2pt#5\kern.2pt}% TEXT
  \FPeval{\myprod}{1/cuts}%
  \clipsize=\myprod\wd\mytext\relax%
  \setcounter{mycount}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{mycount}<\cuts}{%
    \stepcounter{mycount}%
    \edef\NA{\themycount}%
    \edef\NB{\the\numexpr\cuts-\themycount\relax}%
    \FPeval{\myprod}{(\NA-.5)*(\NB+.5)*4/\cuts/\cuts}%
    \ifnum0#1=0\relax%
      \FPeval{\myprod}{1 - \neck*(\myprod)}%
    \else%
      \FPeval{\myprod}{1 - \neck*(1-\myprod)}%
    \fi%
    \clipbox{%
      \value{mycount}\clipsize-\clipsize\relax{} %
      -1pt %
      \wd\mytext-\value{mycount}\clipsize\relax{} %
      -1pt%
    }{\raisebox{#2\dimexpr\ht\mytext-\myprod\ht\mytext}{%
        \scalebox{1}[\myprod]{\usebox{\mytext}}}}%
  }%
}


\makeatletter
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\@cliptoboxdim#1{%
    \setbox #1=\hbox{%
      \Gin@defaultbp\WIDTH{\wd #1}%
      \Gin@defaultbp \DEPTH {\dp #1}%
      \@tempdima \ht #1%
      \advance\@tempdima\dp#1%
      \Gin@defaultbp \TOTALHEIGHT {\@tempdima }%
      \special{pdf:literal q}% 
      \special{pdf:literal 0 -\DEPTH \space \WIDTH \space \TOTALHEIGHT \space re W n }%
      \rlap{\copy #1}%
      \special {pdf:literal Q}%
      \hskip\wd#1%
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{center}

\special{pdf:bcolor [0.0 0.0 0.0] }

\parabtext{0}{.7}{100}{\large TEST TEST TEST}

\end{center}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

This works well when I don't use a custom font, i.e. removing the `\setmainfont` line.

With a custom font the left side of the fonts are chopped off. Below is an example with Helvetica:

[image: Example with Helvetica]

Helvetica isn't so bad, but it gets worse with some other fonts like [Chewy](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Chewy)

[image: Example with Chewy]

Comment: For the readers, I would link this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331780/clipbox-of-a-scalebox-not-working-properly-in-xelatex, as it was a XeLaTeX problem directly related to the prior question.

Comment: My guess is the line, `\savebox{\mytext}{\kern.2pt#5\kern.2pt}%` needs to have the `.2pt` values increased.  That was supposed to account for glyph overhang beyond the bounding box.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if I increased it to something like 5pt will it have any side effects?

Comment: It will change the before/after kerning by that amount.  However, you could compensate for that by undoing that kern on either side of the `\whiledo` loop.  I would add that the slicing process equally subdivides the `\mytext` savebox.  Thus, your resolution decreases slightly, as well, as some slices may be devoted to the blank space in the pre/post kern.

Comment: How would you suggest compensating, because not all fonts will have similar values that are required.

Comment: I would define a new length for that value, with a default setting.  I would reset the length on a font-dependent basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47011/discussion-between-hiemanshu-sharma-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I try to lay out the issues at work.  For my MWE, I only perform 10 vertical slices across the argument, since seeing the actual slices helps, I think, visualize the issue here.

The argument text is set in the `\mytext` savebox.  By definition, the box is only as wide as the space allocated for the glyphs.  Often (some fonts more than others), glyphs extend past the horizontal edges of their allocated boxes.  In this case, the overhanging part of the glyph gets truncated.

The first line of my MWE shows this, where I have artificially made the kern buffer `1pt` less than the actual width of the argument.

In my original answer from the other question, I added a small `.2pt` space buffer before and after the argument (`\savebox{\mytext}{\kern.2pt#5\kern.2pt}`), to try to avoid this truncation.  For some fonts, the OP has found, that buffer is not enough.  So, in my comments above, I proposed creating a length, here called `\bufferzone` that the user can set in a font-dependent way to add that space buffer.  But there are two complications of this:

1. The text gets shifted to the right by `\bufferzone` and has a `\bufferzone` dead space following it (this is shown in the 2nd and 3rd lines of output in my MWE, where `\bufferzone` has been set to `5pt` and `50pt`, respectively); and
2. The buffer zone is also subject to slicing and dicing, and so thre resolution of the remaining slices are decreased as some slices are wasted on empty space.

The correction for item 1 above is to undo the bufferzone, before and after the slicing process, which I do with `\bufferzonecorrection` in my MWE.   This is done for lines 4 and 5 of the output of my MWE. After one becomes convinced on the rightness of this approach, I recommend just replacing `\bufferzonecorrection` in my MWE with `-\bufferzone`.

Item 2 above is not fixable, but its effect can be minimized by selecting `\bufferzone` to the proper value for the selected font.  As such, lines 4 and 5 of the ouput are not "optimized", since several slices are wasted on empty (but non-visible) space, and the result is significantly different from the line 1 output.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen,trimclip,calc,fp,graphicx}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0.2pt}%

%\title{bidPress}
%\author{bidPress}
%\date{September 2016}

%\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=/path/to/fonts/]{"HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf"}

\newsavebox\mytext
\newcounter{mycount}
\newlength\clipsize
\newlength\bufferzone
\newlength\bufferzonecorrection
\bufferzone=.2pt\relax

\newcommand\parabtext[5][0]{%
  \edef\neck{#3}% percent to depress the amplitude
  \def\cuts{#4}% Number of cuts
  \savebox{\mytext}{\kern\bufferzone#5\kern\bufferzone}% TEXT
  \FPeval{\myprod}{1/cuts}%
  \clipsize=\myprod\wd\mytext\relax%
  \setcounter{mycount}{0}%
  \hspace{\bufferzonecorrection}% STEVEN SUGGESTS SETTING TO -\bufferzone
  \whiledo{\value{mycount}<\cuts}{%
    \stepcounter{mycount}%
    \edef\NA{\themycount}%
    \edef\NB{\the\numexpr\cuts-\themycount\relax}%
    \FPeval{\myprod}{(\NA-.5)*(\NB+.5)*4/\cuts/\cuts}%
    \ifnum0#1=0\relax%
      \FPeval{\myprod}{1 - \neck*(\myprod)}%
    \else%
      \FPeval{\myprod}{1 - \neck*(1-\myprod)}%
    \fi%
    \clipbox{%
      \value{mycount}\clipsize-\clipsize\relax{} %
      -1pt %
      \wd\mytext-\value{mycount}\clipsize\relax{} %
      -1pt%
    }{\raisebox{#2\dimexpr\ht\mytext-\myprod\ht\mytext}{%
        \scalebox{1}[\myprod]{\usebox{\mytext}}}}%
  }%
  \hspace{\bufferzonecorrection}% STEVEN SUGGESTS SETTING TO -\bufferzone
}


\makeatletter
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\@cliptoboxdim#1{%
    \setbox #1=\hbox{%
      \Gin@defaultbp\WIDTH{\wd #1}%
      \Gin@defaultbp \DEPTH {\dp #1}%
      \@tempdima \ht #1%
      \advance\@tempdima\dp#1%
      \Gin@defaultbp \TOTALHEIGHT {\@tempdima }%
      \special{pdf:literal q}% 
      \special{pdf:literal 0 -\DEPTH \space \WIDTH \space \TOTALHEIGHT \space re W n }%
      \rlap{\copy #1}%
      \special {pdf:literal Q}%
      \hskip\wd#1%
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\bufferzone=-1pt\relax%
\parabtext{0}{.7}{10}{\large TEST TEST TEST}\rule{5pt}{5pt}

\bufferzone=5pt\relax%
\parabtext{0}{.7}{10}{\large TEST TEST TEST}\rule{5pt}{5pt}

\bufferzone=50pt\relax%
\parabtext{0}{.7}{10}{\large TEST TEST TEST}\rule{5pt}{5pt}

\bufferzone=5pt\relax%
\bufferzonecorrection=-\bufferzone\relax
\parabtext{0}{.7}{10}{\large TEST TEST TEST}\rule{5pt}{5pt}

\bufferzone=50pt\relax%
\bufferzonecorrection=-\bufferzone\relax
\parabtext{0}{.7}{10}{\large TEST TEST TEST}\rule{5pt}{5pt}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]