Short left and right arrows
In answers to previous questions [1,2], people have created ways to produce a right-pointing arrow shorter than the default \rightarrow. However, I'd really like matching left and right ones, and it's not obvious (to me) how to modify those solutions to achieve that.
My use case is as superscripts to decorate a letter - I think the arrows look too long in the following and I'd prefer them to be maybe 60% as long, while still having decent sized heads.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$R^\leftarrow$ and $R^\rightarrow$.
\end{document}

Mockup of desired output:


I don't find the arrows to be too long. Anyway, you can cut the middle third.
Some care is needed because arrows have a quite peculiar bounding box.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sto}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette \virgo_small:nn \to}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sgets}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette \virgo_small:nn \gets}}

\box_new:N \l_virgo_small_left_box
\box_new:N \l_virgo_small_right_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \virgo_small:nn
 {% #1 = math style, #2 = arrow
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_left_box { $#1#2$ }
  \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_virgo_small_left_box
   { 0pt }% left
   { -0.1\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }% bottom
   { 0.6667\box_wd:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }% right
   { -0.4\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }% top
  \box_set_clipped:N \l_virgo_small_left_box
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_right_box { $#1#2$ }
  \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_virgo_small_right_box
   { 0.6667\box_wd:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
   { -0.1\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
   { 0pt }
   { -0.4\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
  \box_set_clipped:N \l_virgo_small_right_box
  \box_use:N \l_virgo_small_left_box 
  \box_use:N \l_virgo_small_right_box 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$X \sto X$

$R^{\to}R^{\gets}$

$R^{\sto}R^{\sgets}$

\end{document}


We can get the short arrows to have the same height and depth of the standard ones.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sto}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette \virgo_small:nn \to}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sgets}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette \virgo_small:nn \gets}}

\box_new:N \l_virgo_small_left_box
\box_new:N \l_virgo_small_right_box
\dim_new:N \l_virgo_small_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l_virgo_small_dp_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \virgo_small:nn
 {% #1 = math style, #2 = arrow
  \hbox:n
   {
    % no math surround
    \dim_set:Nn \mathsurround { 0pt }
    % typeset an arrow in the current math style
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_left_box { $#1#2$ }
    % store height and depth
    \dim_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_ht_dim { \box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_dp_dim { \box_dp:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }
    % trim two thirds at the right
    \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_virgo_small_left_box
     { 0pt }
     { -\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }
     { 0.6667\box_wd:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }
     { -\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_left_box }
    % clip
    \box_set_clipped:N \l_virgo_small_left_box
    % trim two thirds at the left
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_virgo_small_right_box { $#1#2$ }
    \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_virgo_small_right_box
     { 0.6667\box_wd:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
     { -\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
     { 0pt }
     { -\box_ht:N \l_virgo_small_right_box }
    % clip
    \box_set_clipped:N \l_virgo_small_right_box
    % restore height and depth
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l_virgo_small_left_box { \l_virgo_small_ht_dim }
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l_virgo_small_right_box { \l_virgo_small_ht_dim }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_virgo_small_left_box { \l_virgo_small_dp_dim }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_virgo_small_right_box { \l_virgo_small_dp_dim }
    % deliver the boxes
    \box_use_drop:N \l_virgo_small_left_box 
    \box_use_drop:N \l_virgo_small_right_box
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$X \sto X$ {\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt \fbox{$\to$}\fbox{$\sto$}}

$R^{\to}R^{\gets}$

$R^{\sto}R^{\sgets}$

\end{document}



I didn't know \mathpalette, I found the explanation with your answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette. Thanks

From Joseph Wright's answer to this post \clipbox of a \scalebox not working properly in xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\myrightarrow}{
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $\rightarrow$ }
    \box_resize_to_wd:Nn \l_tmpa_box {0.6em}
    \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box { 2pt } { 0pt } { 0pt } {-2pt }
    \box_set_clipped:N \l_tmpa_box
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331780/clipbox-of-a-scalebox-not-working-properly-in-xelatex
A%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { XXX }
\box_scale:Nnn \l_tmpa_box { 1 } { 0.5 }
\box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box { 4pt } { 0pt } { 0pt } { 0pt }
\box_set_clipped:N \l_tmpa_box
\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
\ExplSyntaxOff
B

$\rightarrow$

$R^{\myrightarrow}$
\end{document}


